# Download whole directories in Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I really like how I can easily share files on a network using the SimpleHTTPServer, but I wish there was an option like "download entire directory". Is there an easy (one liner) way to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the sources, e.g. online [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py?annotate=64762).  Right now, if you call the server with a URL that's a directory, its `index.html` file is served, or, missing that, the `list_directory` method is called.  Presumably, you want instead to make a `zip` file with the directory's contents (recursively, I imagine), and serve that?  Obviously there's no way to do it with a one-line change, since you want to replace what are now lines 68-80 (in method `send_head`) plus the whole of method `list_directory`, lines 98-137 -- that's already at least a change to over 50 lines;-).

If you're OK with a change of several dozen lines, not one, and the semantics I've described are what you want, you could of course build the required zipfile as a [`cStringIO.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) object with the [ZipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile-objects) class, and populate it with an [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) on the directory in question (assuming you want, recursively, to get all subdirectories as well).  But it's most definitely not going to be a one-liner;-).

Answer (score 6):

I did that modification for you, I don't know if there'are better ways to do that but:

Just save the file (Ex.: ThreadedHTTPServer.py) and access as:

`$ python -m /path/to/ThreadedHTTPServer PORT`

[BPaste Raw Version](http://bpaste.net/raw/i1D2CWevHxBP1buJrfho/)

The modification also works in threaded way so you won't have problem with download and navigation in the same time, the code aren't organized but:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading
import SimpleHTTPServer
import sys, os, zipfile

PORT = int(sys.argv[1])

def send_head(self):
    """Common code for GET and HEAD commands.

    This sends the response code and MIME headers.

    Return value is either a file object (which has to be copied
    to the outputfile by the caller unless the command was HEAD,
    and must be closed by the caller under all circumstances), or
    None, in which case the caller has nothing further to do.

    """
    path = self.translate_path(self.path)
    f = None

    if self.path.endswith('?download'):

        tmp_file = "tmp.zip"
        self.path = self.path.replace("?download","")

        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(tmp_file, 'w')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if os.path.join(root, file) != os.path.join(root, tmp_file):
                    zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
        zip.close()
        path = self.translate_path(tmp_file)

    elif os.path.isdir(path):

        if not self.path.endswith('/'):
            # redirect browser - doing basically what apache does
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header("Location", self.path + "/")
            self.end_headers()
            return None
        else:

            for index in "index.html", "index.htm":
                index = os.path.join(path, index)
                if os.path.exists(index):
                    path = index
                    break
            else:
                return self.list_directory(path)
    ctype = self.guess_type(path)
    try:
        # Always read in binary mode. Opening files in text mode may cause
        # newline translations, making the actual size of the content
        # transmitted *less* than the content-length!
        f = open(path, 'rb')
    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404, "File not found")
        return None
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", ctype)
    fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs[6]))
    self.send_header("Last-Modified", self.date_time_string(fs.st_mtime))
    self.end_headers()
    return f

def list_directory(self, path):

    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    import cgi, urllib

    """Helper to produce a directory listing (absent index.html).

    Return value is either a file object, or None (indicating an
    error).  In either case, the headers are sent, making the
    interface the same as for send_head().

    """
    try:
        list = os.listdir(path)
    except os.error:
        self.send_error(404, "No permission to list directory")
        return None
    list.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
    f = StringIO()
    displaypath = cgi.escape(urllib.unquote(self.path))
    f.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">')
    f.write("<html>\n<title>Directory listing for %s</title>\n" % displaypath)
    f.write("<body>\n<h2>Directory listing for %s</h2>\n" % displaypath)
    f.write("<a href='%s'>%s</a>\n" % (self.path+"?download",'Download Directory Tree as Zip'))
    f.write("<hr>\n<ul>\n")
    for name in list:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
        displayname = linkname = name
        # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            displayname = name + "/"
            linkname = name + "/"
        if os.path.islink(fullname):
            displayname = name + "@"
            # Note: a link to a directory displays with @ and links with /
        f.write('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>\n'
                % (urllib.quote(linkname), cgi.escape(displayname)))
    f.write("</ul>\n<hr>\n</body>\n</html>\n")
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    self.send_response(200)
    encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=%s" % encoding)
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(length))
    self.end_headers()
    return f

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.send_head = send_head
Handler.list_directory = list_directory

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', PORT), Handler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no one liner which would do it, also what do you mean by "download whole dir" as tar or zip?

Anyway you can follow these steps

1. Derive a class from SimpleHTTPRequestHandler or may be just copy its code
2. Change list_directory method to return a link to "download whole folder"
3. Change copyfile method so that for your links you zip whole dir and return it
4. You may cache zip so that you do not zip folder every time, instead see if any file is modified or not

Would be a fun exercise to do :)

Comment: Unless you also change `send_head`, you're not going to be zipping up directories which contain an `index.html`, so the change is a bit more pervasive than the one you describe (I gave the detail and line numbers for the current online version of the sources in my answer, which crossed yours on the wire by a few seconds).

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way.

An alternative is to use the python script below to download the whole folder recursively. This works well for Python 3. Change the URL as needed.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        yield a.get('href')

def download(url):
    path = urlparse(url).path.lstrip('/')
    print(path)
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('status code is {} for {}'.format(r.status_code, url))
    content = r.text
    if path.endswith('/'):
        Path(path.rstrip('/')).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for link in get_links(content):
            if not link.startswith('.'): # skip hidden files such as .DS_Store
                download(urljoin(url, link))
    else:
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the trailing / indicates a folder
    url = 'http://ed470d37.ngrok.io/a/bc/'
    download(url)
```

Comment: This works, but first you need to install `requests` `bs4` modules using `pip3`

Answer (score 1):

I like @mononoke 's solution. But there are several problems in it. They are

- write files in text mode
- sometimes`href` and `text` are different, especially for non-ascii path
- not download large file block-wisely

I tried to fix these problems：

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math

def get_links(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        yield a.get('href'), a.get_text()

def download(url, path=None, overwrite=False):
    if path is None:
        path = urlparse(url).path.lstrip('/')
    if url.endswith('/'):
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception('status code is {} for {}'.format(r.status_code, url))
        content = r.text
        Path(path.rstrip('/')).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for link, name in get_links(content):
            if not link.startswith('.'): # skip hidden files such as .DS_Store
                download(urljoin(url, link), os.path.join(path, name))
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print("#existing", path)
            if not overwrite:
                return
        chunk_size = 1024*1024
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        content_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
        total = math.ceil(content_size / chunk_size)
        print("#", path)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            c = 0
            st = 100
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                c += 1
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                ap = int(c*st/total) - int((c-1)*st/total)
                if ap > 0:
                    print("#" * ap, end="")
            print("\r  "," "*int(c*st/total), "\r", end="")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the trailing / indicates a folder
    url = 'http://ed470d37.ngrok.io/a/bc/'
    download(url, "/data/bc")
```